# Creating an android ffmpeg executable

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

How do I do this? I dont want to use ffmpeg in an app programatically using the ndk / jni wrapper, I just want to compile a single binary/executable file that I can put in system/bin on the device and run from terminal.

Hi have tried William Seemann suggestion but it will not build the executable, when i try the default configure_everything.sh as it says in the docs i get lots of "file to patch errors" console output http://pastebin.com/m0uz5fx2

if i try the make_ffmpeg.sh script as william sggests then i get

```
brx@router ~/Documents/android-ffmpeg-master $ NDK_BASE=/home/brx/Documents/android-ndk-r6b ./make_ffmpeg.sh 
~/Documents/android-ffmpeg-master ~/Documents/android-ffmpeg-master
~/Documents/android-ffmpeg-master/ffmpeg ~/Documents/android-ffmpeg-master ~/Documents/android-ffmpeg-master
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'. Stop.
~/Documents/android-ffmpeg-master ~/Documents/android-ffmpeg-master
~/Documents/android-ffmpeg-master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the script (make_ffmpeg.sh) in [this](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) project will meet your needs.

Comment: was the ffmpeg you sent me (the first one) x264 enabled? if not could you please build it for me for some reasons the guardian scripts from git dont work for me I get lots of hunk errors, something to do with git

Comment: p.s i hope this isnt a bother for you

Comment: I'll take a look and get back to you. Not a problem.

Comment: did you received the ffmpeg? how can you use inside an android eclipse project? i need some help how to use in android app.